# BjyAuthorize object_manager

Tags: php, zend-framework, bjyauthorize

I am trying to make ZfcUser, ZfcAdmin and BjyAuthorize work together.

Now i am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\Exc`eption\ServiceNotFoundException' with message
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create
>   an instance for My\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager' in
>   C:\path_to_project\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php
>   on line 495`

I am not using Doctrine in this project.
I already found out that the problem lies in bjyauthorize.global.php file.

I need to change the object_manager.

Since I am not so familiar with Zend Framework 2 or BjyAuthorize yet.
Now I just don't have a clue what I need to enter here.

Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you, though it is probably late for you, if anyone else has issues:
**Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager** or **Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager**

Even better, here is a good guide (scroll to bottom if you simply wish to download module):
http://samminds.com/2013/03/zfcuser-bjyauthorize-and-doctrine-working-together/